# How to add a value based on a condition in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We are looking to satisfy a formula in excel, `= BASEVALUE + WEIGHTVALUE*#EVIDENCEPIECES`

Basically, For Level 1 It has a `BASEVALUE = 4` and `WEIGHTVALUE = .05`, so, when you have 12 Pieces of "Level 1" Evidence it would `= 4 +.5*12`.

We have a column that has the `WEIGHTVALUE*#EVIDENCE PIECES (P3)`, and we are trying to figure out how to conditionally add `BASEVALUE` (for Level 1 `Evidence = N1`) when P3 does not equal 0.

At the moment, we're running into an error whereby no matter what formula we've tried, it always adds N1 (4) to cells that have 0.

We want cells with 0 value to stay at 0, but any value above 0 to have 4 added.

> [image]

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Answer (score 0):

Your current formula is adding N1 value regardless of P value. If you simply want to add N1 if P is not zero, then use this formula:

```
=IF(P3=0,0,P3+$N$1)
```

You have a lot more details in your question (such as multiplying by pieces), but I don't see where that's relevant to your question. It seems like you can remove the first three paragraphs from your question unless you are also needing help with that part too.